# Resizing image height and width according to device screen

Tags: android, css, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

How can i display my image on the full screen of different devices i.e. auto adjusting the image according to device display?

I have tried "Width : Device-width" option but didn't succeed. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution for this. I follow the "@media queries" concept in my css and it done the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

check if this css helps your code!!

```
   html, body {
        width:100%; /* this is a must */
        height:100%; /* this is a must */
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
    img {
        width:100%; /* this will depend on parent containers width */
        height:auto;
    }
```

[**see demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/r3Fd2/) (*re-size browser width and height to see the change*)